Transform ARM assembly v5 color scheme for programmer's notepad into IDEA color scheme
I am trying to move from my old IDE for programming Assembly into CLion. I would like to have the same color scheme that I have in programmer's notepad.
Does somebody know how can I transform the data of the schema from programmer's notepad into the format for IDEA IDEs?
Here is the color scheme for ARM assembly in programmer's notepad:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Scheme>
    <keyword-classes>
        <!-- common ARMv4 registers -->
        <keyword-class name="arm_registers">
            r0 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 r10 r11 r12 r13 r14 r15
            fp ip sp lr pc cpsr spsr
        </keyword-class>
        <!-- common ARMv4 instructions -->
        <keyword-class name="arm_instructions">
            add adds adc adcs sub subs sbc sbcs rsc rscs rsb rsbs cmp cmn
            mul muls mla mlas umull umulls umlal umlals smull smulls smlal smlals
            and ands bic bics eor eors orr orrs tst teq
            mov movs mvn mvns mrs msr swp swpb
            ldr ldrb ldrsb ldsb ldrh ldrsh ldsh ldrt ldrbt
            str strb strh strt strbt
            ldmia ldmib ldmda ldmdb ldmfd ldmfa ldmea ldmed
            stmia stmib stmda stmdb stmfd stmfa stmea stmed
            b bl bx blx
            pop push adr adrl nop swi
        </keyword-class>
        <!-- ARM logical shifts -->
        <keyword-class name="logical_shifts">
            asr lsl lsr ror rrx
        </keyword-class>
        <!-- common ARMv4 coprocessor and some ARMv5 extended instructions -->
        <keyword-class name="copro_instructions">
            pld cdp ldc ldcl stc stcl ldrd strd mcr mrc mcrr mrrc
            ldc2 ldc2l stc2 stc2l cdp2 mcr2 mrc2
            qadd qdadd qsub qdsub clz bkpt neg
        </keyword-class>
        <!-- some of the ARM predicated (conditional) instructions -->
        <keyword-class name="pred_instructions">
            beq bne bcs bhs bcc blo bmi bpl bvs bvc bhi bls bge blt bgt ble bal
            bleq blne blcs blhs blcc bllo blmi blpl blvs blvc blhi blls blge bllt blgt blle blal
            bxeq bxne bxcs bxhs bxcc bxlo bxmi bxpl bxvs bxvc bxhi bxls bxge bxlt bxgt bxle bxal
            blxeq blxne blxcs blxhs blxcc blxlo blxmi blxpl blxvs blxvc blxhi blxls blxge blxlt blxgt blxle
            moveq movne movcs movhs movcc movlo movmi movpl movvs movvc movhi movls movge movlt movgt movle
            mvneq mvnne mvncs mvnhs mvncc mvnlo mvnmi mvnpl mvnvs mvnvc mvnhi mvnls mvnge mvnlt mvngt mvnle
            mrseq mrsne mrscs mrshs mrscc mrslo mrsmi mrspl mrsvs mrsvc mrshi mrsls mrsge mrslt mrsgt mrsle
            msreq msrne msrcs msrhs msrcc msrlo msrmi msrpl msrvs msrvc msrhi msrls msrge msrlt msrgt msrle
            addeq addne addcs addhs addcc addlo addmi addpl addvs addvc addhi addls addge addlt addgt addle
            adceq adcne adccs adchs adccc adclo adcmi adcpl adcvs adcvc adchi adcls adcge adclt adcgt adcle
            subeq subne subcs subhs subcc sublo submi subpl subvs subvc subhi subls subge sublt subgt suble
            sbceq sbcne sbccs sbchs sbccc sbclo sbcmi sbcpl sbcvs sbcvc sbchi sbcls sbcge sbclt sbcgt sbcle
            rsbeq rsbne rsbcs rsbhs rsbcc rsblo rsbmi rsbpl rsbvs rsbvc rsbhi rsbls rsbge rsblt rsbgt rsble
            rsceq rscne rsccs rschs rsccc rsclo rscmi rscpl rscvs rscvc rschi rscls rscge rsclt rscgt rscle
            muleq mulne mulcs mulhs mulcc mullo mulmi mulpl mulvs mulvc mulhi mulls mulge mullt mulgt mulle
            mlaeq mlane mlacs mlahs mlacc mlalo mlami mlapl mlavs mlavc mlahi mlals mlage mlalt mlagt mlale
            umulleq umullne umullcs umullhs umullcc umulllo umullmi umullpl umullvs umullvc umullhi umullls umullge umulllt umullgt umullle
            umlaleq umlalne umlalcs umlalhs umlalcc umlallo umlalmi umlalpl umlalvs umlalvc umlalhi umlalls umlalge umlallt umlalgt umlalle
            smulleq smullne smullcs smullhs smullcc smulllo smullmi smullpl smullvs smullvc smullhi smullls smullge smulllt smullgt smullle
            smlaleq smlalne smlalcs smlalhs smlalcc smlallo smlalmi smlalpl smlalvs smlalvc smlalhi smlalls smlalge smlallt smlalgt smlalle
            cmpeq cmpne cmpcs cmphs cmpcc cmplo cmpmi cmppl cmpvs cmpvc cmphi cmpls cmpge cmplt cmpgt cmple
            cmneq cmnne cmncs cmnhs cmncc cmnlo cmnmi cmnpl cmnvs cmnvc cmnhi cmnls cmnge cmnlt cmngt cmnle
            tsteq tstne tstcs tsths tstcc tstlo tstmi tstpl tstvs tstvc tsthi tstls tstge tstlt tstgt tstle
            teqeq teqne teqcs teqhs teqcc teqlo teqmi teqpl teqvs teqvc teqhi teqls teqge teqlt teqgt teqle
            andeq andne andcs andhs andcc andlo andmi andpl andvs andvc andhi andls andge andlt andgt andle
            eoreq eorne eorcs eorhs eorcc eorlo eormi eorpl eorvs eorvc eorhi eorls eorge eorlt eorgt eorle
            orreq orrne orrcs orrhs orrcc orrlo orrmi orrpl orrvs orrvc orrhi orrls orrge orrlt orrgt orrle
            biceq bicne biccs bichs biccc biclo bicmi bicpl bicvs bicvc bichi bicls bicge biclt bicgt bicle
            ldreq ldrne ldrcs ldrhs ldrcc ldrlo ldrmi ldrpl ldrvs ldrvc ldrhi ldrls ldrge ldrlt ldrgt ldrle
            streq strne strcs strhs strcc strlo strmi strpl strvs strvc strhi strls strge strlt strgt strle
            swpeq swpne swpcs swphs swpcc swplo swpmi swppl swpvs swpvc swphi swpls swpge swplt swpgt swple
            cdpeq cdpne cdpcs cdphs cdpcc cdplo cdpmi cdppl cdpvs cdpvc cdphi cdpls cdpge cdplt cdpgt cdple
            mrceq mrcne mrccs mrchs mrccc mrclo mrcmi mrcpl mrcvs mrcvc mrchi mrcls mrcge mrclt mrcgt mrcle
            mcreq mcrne mcrcs mcrhs mcrcc mcrlo mcrmi mcrpl mcrvs mcrvc mcrhi mcrls mcrge mcrlt mcrgt mcrle
            ldceq ldcne ldccs ldchs ldccc ldclo ldcmi ldcpl ldcvs ldcvc ldchi ldcls ldcge ldclt ldcgt ldcle
            stceq stcne stccs stchs stccc stclo stcmi stcpl stcvs stcvc stchi stcls stcge stclt stcgt stcle
            swieq swine swics swihs swicc swilo swimi swipl swivs swivc swihi swils swige swilt swigt swile
            clzeq clzne clzcs clzhs clzcc clzlo clzmi clzpl clzvs clzvc clzhi clzls clzge clzlt clzgt clzle
            moveqs movnes movcss movhss movccs movlos movmis movpls movvss movvcs movhis movlss movges movlts movgts movles
            mvneqs mvnnes mvncss mvnhss mvnccs mvnlos mvnmis mvnpls mvnvss mvnvcs mvnhis mvnlss mvnges mvnlts mvngts mvnles
            addeqs addnes addcss addhss addccs addlos addmis addpls addvss addvcs addhis addlss addges addlts addgts addles
            adceqs adcnes adccss adchss adcccs adclos adcmis adcpls adcvss adcvcs adchis adclss adcges adclts adcgts adcles
            subeqs subnes subcss subhss subccs sublos submis subpls subvss subvcs subhis sublss subges sublts subgts subles
            sbceqs sbcnes sbccss sbchss sbcccs sbclos sbcmis sbcpls sbcvss sbcvcs sbchis sbclss sbcges sbclts sbcgts sbcles
            rsbeqs rsbnes rsbcss rsbhss rsbccs rsblos rsbmis rsbpls rsbvss rsbvcs rsbhis rsblss rsbges rsblts rsbgts rsbles
            rsceqs rscnes rsccss rschss rscccs rsclos rscmis rscpls rscvss rscvcs rschis rsclss rscges rsclts rscgts rscles
            muleqs mulnes mulcss mulhss mulccs mullos mulmis mulpls mulvss mulvcs mulhis mullss mulges mullts mulgts mulles
            mlaeqs mlanes mlacss mlahss mlaccs mlalos mlamis mlapls mlavss mlavcs mlahis mlalss mlages mlalts mlagts mlales
            umulleqs umullnes umullcss umullhss umullccs umulllos umullmis umullpls umullvss umullvcs umullhis umulllss umullges umulllts umullgts umullles
            umlaleqs umlalnes umlalcss umlalhss umlalccs umlallos umlalmis umlalpls umlalvss umlalvcs umlalhis umlallss umlalges umlallts umlalgts umlalles
            smulleqs smullnes smullcss smullhss smullccs smulllos smullmis smullpls smullvss smullvcs smullhis smulllss smullges smulllts smullgts smullles
            smlaleqs smlalnes smlalcss smlalhss smlalccs smlallos smlalmis smlalpls smlalvss smlalvcs smlalhis smlallss smlalges smlallts smlalgts smlalles
            andeqs andnes andcss andhss andccs andlos andmis andpls andvss andvcs andhis andlss andges andlts andgts andles
            eoreqs eornes eorcss eorhss eorccs eorlos eormis eorpls eorvss eorvcs eorhis eorlss eorges eorlts eorgts eorles
            orreqs orrnes orrcss orrhss orrccs orrlos orrmis orrpls orrvss orrvcs orrhis orrlss orrges orrlts orrgts orrles
            biceqs bicnes biccss bichss bicccs biclos bicmis bicpls bicvss bicvcs bichis biclss bicges biclts bicgts bicles
            ldreqb ldrneb ldrcsb ldrhsb ldrccb ldrlob ldrmib ldrplb ldrvsb ldrvcb ldrhib ldrlsb ldrgeb ldrltb ldrgtb ldrleb
            streqb strneb strcsb strhsb strccb strlob strmib strplb strvsb strvcb strhib strlsb strgeb strltb strgtb strleb
            swpeqb swpneb swpcsb swphsb swpccb swplob swpmib swpplb swpvsb swpvcb swphib swplsb swpgeb swpltb swpgtb swpleb
            ldreqsb ldrnesb ldrcssb ldrhssb ldrccsb ldrlosb ldrmisb ldrplsb ldrvssb ldrvcsb ldrhisb ldrlssb ldrgesb ldrltsb ldrgtsb ldrlesb
            ldseqb ldsneb ldscsb ldshsb ldsccb ldslob ldsmib ldsplb ldsvsb ldsvcb ldshib ldslsb ldsgeb ldsltb ldsgtb ldsleb
            ldreqh ldrneh ldrcsh ldrhsh ldrcch ldrloh ldrmih ldrplh ldrvsh ldrvch ldrhih ldrlsh ldrgeh ldrlth ldrgth ldrleh
            streqh strneh strcsh strhsh strcch strloh strmih strplh strvsh strvch strhih strlsh strgeh strlth strgth strleh
            ldreqsh ldrnesh ldrcssh ldrhssh ldrccsh ldrlosh ldrmish ldrplsh ldrvssh ldrvcsh ldrhish ldrlssh ldrgesh ldrltsh ldrgtsh ldrlesh
            ldseqh ldsneh ldscsh ldshsh ldscch ldsloh ldsmih ldsplh ldsvsh ldsvch ldshih ldslsh ldsgeh ldslth ldsgth ldsleh
        </keyword-class>
        <!-- GAS (GNU Assembler) directives -->
        <keyword-class name="gas_directives">
            .arm .thumb .code .include .align .balign .end .fail .err .print .comm
            .section .text .rodata .data .bss .struct .org .pool .func .endfunc .thumb_func
            .equ .set .equiv .global .globl .fill .zero .space .skip .def
            .byte .hword .word .ascii .asciz .quad .float .double
        </keyword-class>
        
    </keyword-classes>

    <language name="asm" title="Assembler" folding="false">
        <lexer name="asm" />
        <use-keywords>
            <keyword key="0" name="ARM Instructions" class="arm_instructions"/>
            <keyword key="1" name="Coprocessor Instructions" class="copro_instructions"/>
            <keyword key="2" name="Registers" class="arm_registers"/>
            <keyword key="3" name="Directives" class="gas_directives"/>
            <keyword key="4" name="Logical Shifts" class="logical_shifts"/>
            <keyword key="5" name="Predicated Instructions" class="pred_instructions"/>
        </use-keywords>
        <use-styles>
            <style name="Default" key="32" fore="000000" />
            <style name="Whitespace" key="0" />
            <style name="Comment" key="1" fore="008000" />
            <style name="Number" key="2" fore="F000F0" />
            <style name="String" key="3" fore="5E11A6" />
            <style name="Operator" key="4" fore="99284C" />
            <style name="Identifier" key="5" fore="202020" />
            <style name="ARM instruction" key="6" fore="2040FF" bold="true" />
            <style name="Coprocessor instruction" key="7" fore="2040FF" italic="true" />
            <style name="Register" key="8" fore="2040FF" />
            <style name="Directive" key="9" fore="FF0000" />
            <style name="Logical shift" key="10" fore="F08020" />
            <!-- <style name="Comment block (GNU as /*...*/ syntax, unimplemented)" key="11" class="commentbox" /> -->
            <style name="Single Quote String" key="12" fore="116A5A" />
            <style name="Unclosed String" key="13" fore="000000" back="E0C0E0" eolfilled="true" />
            <style name="Predicated instruction" key="14" fore="2040FF" bold="true" italic="true" />
        </use-styles>
    </language>
</Scheme>

and here is the default color scheme in CLion:
<code_scheme name="Default" version="173">
  <RiderCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppClangFormat/EnableClangFormatSupport/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/EditorConfig/EnableClangFormatSupport/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_BINARY_EXPRESSIONS_CHAIN/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_CALLS_CHAIN/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_EXPRESSION/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_FOR_STMT/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTIPLE_DECLARATION/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_TERNARY/@EntryValue" value="ALIGN_ALL" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/BLANK_LINES_AROUND_CLASS_DEFINITION/@EntryValue" value="1" type="int" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_DECLARATIONS/@EntryValue" value="2" type="int" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE/@EntryValue" value="2" type="int" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/KEEP_USER_LINEBREAKS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INDENT_CASE_FROM_SWITCH/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INDENT_COMMENT/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INT_ALIGN_EQ/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SIMPLE_BLOCK_STYLE/@EntryValue" value="DO_NOT_CHANGE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_COMMA_IN_TEMPLATE_ARGS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_COMMA_IN_TEMPLATE_PARAMS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_FOR_SEMICOLON/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_FOR_SEMICOLON/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_UNARY_OPERATOR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_ARRAY_ACCESS_BRACKETS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_CAST_EXPRESSION_PARENTHESES/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_EMPTY_INITIALIZER_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_EMPTY_METHOD_PARENTHESES/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_INITIALIZER_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPECIAL_ELSE_IF_TREATMENT/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_CAST_EXPRESSION_PARENTHESES/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_AFTER_BINARY_OPSIGN/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_BEFORE_TERNARY_OPSIGNS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/TYPE_DECLARATION_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/OTHER_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/CASE_BLOCK_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/BLANK_LINES_AROUND_FUNCTION_DECLARATION/@EntryValue" value="1" type="int" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/BLANK_LINES_AROUND_FUNCTION_DEFINITION/@EntryValue" value="1" type="int" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/PLACE_WHILE_ON_NEW_LINE/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/PLACE_ELSE_ON_NEW_LINE/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/PLACE_CATCH_ON_NEW_LINE/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/NAMESPACE_INDENTATION/@EntryValue" value="All" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_ARGUMENT/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_EXTENDS_LIST/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETER/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_TYPE_ARGUMENT/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ALIGN_MULTILINE_TYPE_PARAMETER/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/BLANK_LINES_AROUND_DECLARATIONS/@EntryValue" value="0" type="int" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INDENT_ACCESS_SPECIFIERS_FROM_CLASS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INDENT_CLASS_MEMBERS_FROM_ACCESS_SPECIFIERS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/LINE_BREAK_AFTER_COLON_IN_MEMBER_INITIALIZER_LISTS/@EntryValue" value="ON_SINGLE_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/MEMBER_INITIALIZER_LIST_STYLE/@EntryValue" value="DO_NOT_CHANGE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/PLACE_NAMESPACE_DEFINITIONS_ON_SAME_LINE/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_COLON_IN_BITFIELD_DECLARATOR/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_COLON_IN_BITFIELD_DECLARATOR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_EXTENDS_COLON/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_EXTENDS_COLON/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_FOR_COLON/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_FOR_COLON/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_PTR_IN_DATA_MEMBER/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_PTR_IN_DATA_MEMBERS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_PTR_IN_METHOD/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_PTR_IN_NESTED_DECLARATOR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_REF_IN_DATA_MEMBER/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_REF_IN_DATA_MEMBERS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_AFTER_REF_IN_METHOD/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_PTR_IN_ABSTRACT_DECL/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_PTR_IN_DATA_MEMBER/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_PTR_IN_DATA_MEMBERS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_PTR_IN_METHOD/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_REF_IN_ABSTRACT_DECL/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_REF_IN_DATA_MEMBER/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_REF_IN_DATA_MEMBERS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_REF_IN_METHOD/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_TEMPLATE_ARGS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BEFORE_TEMPLATE_PARAMS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_BETWEEN_CLOSING_ANGLE_BRACKETS_IN_TEMPLATE_ARGS/@EntryValue" value="true" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_EMPTY_TEMPLATE_PARAMS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_TEMPLATE_ARGS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_TEMPLATE_PARAMS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_DECLARATION_PARENTHESES/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/SPACE_WITHIN_EMPTY_BLOCKS/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_BEFORE_INVOCATION_LPAR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_AFTER_INVOCATION_LPAR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_BEFORE_INVOCATION_RPAR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_BEFORE_DECLARATION_LPAR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_AFTER_DECLARATION_LPAR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_BEFORE_DECLARATION_RPAR/@EntryValue" value="false" type="bool" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_ARGUMENTS_STYLE/@EntryValue" value="WRAP_IF_LONG" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/WRAP_PARAMETERS_STYLE/@EntryValue" value="WRAP_IF_LONG" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/BREAK_TEMPLATE_DECLARATION/@EntryValue" value="LINE_BREAK" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/NAMESPACE_DECLARATION_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/FREE_BLOCK_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INVOCABLE_DECLARATION_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/ANONYMOUS_METHOD_DECLARATION_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INITIALIZER_BRACES/@EntryValue" value="END_OF_LINE_NO_SPACE" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INDENT_STYLE/@EntryValue" value="Space" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/INDENT_SIZE/@EntryValue" value="4" type="int" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/CONTINUOUS_LINE_INDENT/@EntryValue" value="Double" type="string" />
    <option name="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CppFormatting/TAB_WIDTH/@EntryValue" value="4" type="int" />
  </RiderCodeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>

Can someone at least tell me how do I begin? thank you
